# inputting a certain number for wages doesn't stop the do while loop when it reaches the number

Tags: c

```
   #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char firstname[20];
char lastname[20]; 
float wage;
int n_emp;
int e_numemp;
FILE *staff_ptr;

staff_ptr=fopen ("staff", "wage");
printf("Input the numbers employees you would like to add\n");
scanf("%d",&n_emp);
do {
  (e_numemp=n_emp-1);
  printf("Enter the first name of the employee\n");
  scanf("%s",&firstname);
  printf("Enter the second name of the employee\n");
  scanf("%s",&lastname);
  printf("Enter the wage of the employee\n");
  scanf("%f",&wage);
  fwrite (&firstname,sizeof (firstname),1,staff_ptr);
  fwrite (&lastname,sizeof (lastname),1,staff_ptr );
  fwrite (&wage,sizeof (wage),1,staff_ptr );
}
while (e_numemp!=0);
fclose (staff_ptr);
return 0;
}
```

The question for my assignment is "Write a program to ask for the name and wage of each employee in a firm and store the data in a file called "staff"

For some reason when i input a number like 4 for the numbers of employees it just doesn't stop at 4 and keeps going on forever

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn how to do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and step thru it to examine the flow and variables as it runs. Surely you can at least examine the loop variable and see why it isn't reaching zero. More tips: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: May not be the cause of your problem but `fopen ("staff", "wage");` looks wrong. The second argument is supposed to be the mode.

Comment: One of those situations where a second set of eyes or peer review sometimes helps. I've had similar logic missteps over the years. Glad I can help with my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every iteration of the loop `e_numemp` is always set to `n_emp - 1` (n_emp is never changed once input).
Assuming you wanted to save the initial value of `n_emp`, perhaps you meant:

```
scanf("%d",&n_emp);
e_numemp = n_emp;
do {
  e_numemp -= 1;
  .
  .
  .
} while ( e_numemp != 0 );
```